# XML isn't being written to my file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml file I'm trying to add some data to. The code to write i is executing without any error, but I don't see anything happening.

The XML File looks like:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Instance>
  ...
  </Instance>
  <Instance>
  ...
  </Instance>
</NewDataSet>
```

I write to it with

```
            Dim sys_file As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
            sys_file.Load(SysFilePath)

            With sys_file.SelectSingleNode("/NewDataSet").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
                .WriteStartElement("Instance")
                .WriteElementString("UID", guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .WriteEndElement()
            End With


            sys_file.Save(SysFilePath)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `XmlWriter` to write:

```
Dim sys_file As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
sys_file.Load(SysFilePath)

Using xw As System.Xml.XmlWriter = sys_file.SelectSingleNode("/NewDataSet").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
    With xw
        .WriteStartElement("Instance")
        .WriteElementString("UID", guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()
    End With
End Using

sys_file.Save(SysFilePath)
```

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks for the contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

An [alternative approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) is using `CreateElement()` and `AppendChild()`:

```vb
' Create the XmlDocument.
Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml("<NewDataSet><Instance>...</Instance><Instance>...</Instance></NewDataSet>")
' doc.Load(SysFilePath)  ' or load the XML from a file.

' Create a 'UID' element. 
Dim uidElement as XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("UID")
uidElement.InnerText = guid.NewGuid().ToString()

' Create an 'Instance' element.
Dim instanceElement as XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Instance")

' Append 'UID' to 'Instance'.
instanceElement.AppendChild(uidElement)

' Append 'Instance' to the document.
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(instanceElement)

' Save the document to a file. White space is 
' preserved (no white space).
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true
doc.Save(SysFilePath)
```